# Responsive Scrollable Frame in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a body of text that is currently responsive.

```
<div class = "col-sm-6 col-xs-6>
  <div class = "well">
    <p> A lot of text... </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the text to be scrollable (within the well), but I would like the max height of the well to change based on the screen size.

The following makes the well scrollable but I am not sure how 
to have the custom heights... one for sm and one for xs.

```
.scroll_for_sm {
  height: 500px !important;
  overflow: scroll;
}


.scroll_for_xs {
  height: 250px !important;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the height of the well to respond according to the screen size (or height in this matter), just specify a height to your body so in your css, add this:

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    min-height: 100% !important;
}
```

and then, for the well, add this css:

```
.well{
    height:100%;
}
```

(The percentages can be changed to pixels, em, %, etc and valued accordingly depending on what you want)